# Error creating Javadoc, Could not launch Javadoc command

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc

Friends, 
I do not succeed to create Javadocs for my Android project.

What I do:

1. Project - Create Javadoc
2. Enter in the following parameters into the popped up window 
   for "Javadoc command:"    C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\android.jar
   because my project is set to API 10.
3. I choose one class out of a package that ends with .java
4. enter for the parameter "use standart doclet Destination:" C:\Users\MR WULF\Desktop what i assume means just save the ready document on the desktop

the error that it shows after hiting the "Finish button" :

Could not launch Javadoc command
Reason: cannot run program:  C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\android.jar
Create process error=193, %1 is not a valid WIN-32 function

Would be glad about any support.

Comment: Hey Rob, I use Eclipse, should have mentioned that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the android.jar as the command to run, which doesn't work and causes the error you've described. "Javadoc command" expects a path to the javadoc binary, for example

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\javadoc.exe
```

With that, it should do what you expect ;)